# SwiftUI onReceive is it possible to get oldValue?

Tags: swiftui, tabview, didset

I have a custom TabView and I want to Bind to a State to change tabs. I also want to detect if the user has tapped the same tab again in order to scroll to the top of that view.

didSet isn't called when I use a binding. onChange isn't called because the value hasn't changed, and onReceive doesn't give me the old value to compare.

Any ideas? (Trying to avoid using a published property)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var scrollToTop1: Bool = false
    @State private var scrollToTop2: Bool = false
    
    @State private var selectedTab: Int = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                NavigationView {
                    View1(scrollToTop: $scrollToTop1)
                }
                .tag(1)
                
                NavigationView {
                    View2(scrollToTop: $scrollToTop2)
                }
                .tag(2)
            }
            .onReceive(Just(selectedTab)) { [oldValue = selectedTab] newValue in
                print("Old: \(oldValue)") //Shows newValue
                print("New: \(newValue)")
                if oldValue == newValue {
                    switch selectedTab {
                    case 1:
                        scrollToTop1.toggle()
                    case 2:
                        scrollToTop2.toggle()
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
            
            TabBar(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
        }
    }
}

struct TabBar: View {
    @Binding var selectedTab: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TabItem(selectedTab: $selectedTab, text: "View 1", tab: 1)
            TabItem(selectedTab: $selectedTab, text: "View 2", tab: 2)
        }
        .background(Color.green)
    }
}

struct TabItem: View {
    @Binding var selectedTab: Int
    let text: String
    let tab: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            selectedTab = tab
        } label: {
            Text(text)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .frame(height: 50)
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help to have a code sample to go from. In general, with a `Publisher`, you can use `scan` to get old values.

Comment: @jnpdx thanks for your reply. I've updated my question to include sample code. Scan looks like what I'm after! Could you show example code of how to use it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a great scenario for a custom `Binding`, where you can intercept the value before its set and compare it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var scrollToTop1: Bool = false
    @State private var scrollToTop2: Bool = false
    
    @State private var selectedTab: Int = 1
    
    var customBinding: Binding<Int> {
        .init {
            selectedTab
        } set: { newValue in
            print("New value: ", newValue)
            if newValue == selectedTab {
                print("Scroll to top")
            }
            selectedTab = newValue
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            TabView(selection: customBinding) {
                NavigationView {
                    Text("1")
                }
                .tag(1)
                
                NavigationView {
                    Text("2")
                }
                .tag(2)
            }
            
            TabBar(selectedTab: customBinding)
        }
    }
}

struct TabBar: View {
    @Binding var selectedTab: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TabItem(selectedTab: $selectedTab, text: "View 1", tab: 1)
            TabItem(selectedTab: $selectedTab, text: "View 2", tab: 2)
        }
        .background(Color.green)
    }
}
```